# If statement with multiple condition checks not working properly

Tags: php

I have been trying to get my PHP if statement code to check multiple titles and first names for the titles but I can only get it to work for the first title and name for example.

This code works great:

```
if((!empty($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] === 'Select' && empty($_POST['first_name']))){
    echo 'error';
}
```

But when I add the following line of code `|| (!empty($_POST['title_2']) && $_POST['title_2'] === 'Select' && empty($_POST['first_name_2']))` to the if statement my code will not work at all I was wondering how can I fix this problem?

None working code:

```
if((!empty($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] === 'Select' && empty($_POST['first_name'])) || (!empty($_POST['title_2']) && $_POST['title_2'] === 'Select' && empty($_POST['first_name_2']))){
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to use `isset` then check that they all equal `select`. `isset` can take multiple variables. What happens with this code, error, no response?

Comment: I tried that already but I get the same results.

Comment: What is the response? The second `)` here, `empty($_POST['first_name']))` looks like it is closing your `if`. Is error reporting on and are you checking the logs?

Comment: Let me take another look at my code.

Comment: Must be a lot of code?

Comment: Try to add an else and in it print the values of the 6 variables. Use var_dump in the else to get the real value. Check all is as you are expecting.

Comment: And can you explain what does it mean "does not work at all"? Errors? Blank page? Wrong behavior? What?